# Drift/Moor/Flutter StateError (Bad state: No element) when selecting single row with getSingle()

Tags: flutter, sqlite, flutter-moor, drift, moor

When retrieving data from a Drift database using the `.getSingle()` method, if there is no row matching the search criterion, a `StateError (Bad state: No element)` error is thrown. Is this expected behavior?

```
  Future<MyData> singleMyData(String id) {
    return (select(myDatas)..where((t) => t.id.equals(id)))
        .getSingle();
  }
```

...

```
var singleData = await myDatabase.singleMyData("theId");
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the element is not in the database. Try this instead:

```html
// can return empty list
  Future<List<DATA>> lookForSong(String songId) {
    return (select(records)..where((tbl) => tbl.uid.equals(recordId))).get();
  }

// data is sure to be present
  Future<DATA> getSong(String songId) {
    return (select(records)..where((tbl) => tbl.uid.equals(recordId))).getSingle();
  }
```